# Fail to install certain version package with Conda install

Tags: python, installation, conda, local

I am trying to install a specific version of TopHat (v. 2.0.14) in my conda (v. 4.10.3) environment (built on python 2.7). I cannot download this version because it cannot be found from any channel. The TopHat can be downloaded from [TopHat](http://ccb.jhu.edu/software/tophat/downloads/)

The operating system of my computer is macOS Mojave Version 10.14.6, so I chose OSX_x86_64 and downloaded it.

Back to my terminal, I tried to install with the following code:

```
conda install --offline /Users/kenhsu/Desktop/tophat-2.0.14/tophat-    
2.0.14.OSX_x86_64.tar
conda install --use-local /Users/kenhsu/Desktop/tophat-2.0.14/tophat-   
2.0.14.OSX_x86_64.tar
```

They both failed and reported as below:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current    
channels:

- /users/kenhsu/desktop/tophat-2.0.14/tophat-2.0.14.osx_x86_64.tar

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I need this version of TopHat to process the example data from coursera class.

Answer (score 1):

Those `*.tar` files are not Conda packages. As such, Conda does not know how to install them. It looks like you can simply extract them and look at the `README` file within to see how to use it.

If you want to install with Conda, the package appears to be available from the [Bioconda channel](https://anaconda.org/search?q=tophat). You can run

```
conda install -c bioconda tophat
```

to install.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to use certain version package because the exam from coursera asked me to use the older version of these packages.

Comment: I wonder if I can simply download and use them, or make any change to these downloaded files to make them install in the Conda environment.

Comment: I don't know. Conda usually has multiple versions available, if you know the specific version you can put `conda install -c bioconda tophat==1.0.0` or something similar

Comment: Yeah. I tried this command line before, but it also fail for some unknown reason.

Comment: If you put the error message into a new question, or search for the error message, it would be possible to help fix that error instead...